# simple html dom parser get text without tag

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I want to parse a HTML object using simple HTML DOM parser using PHP. The specific part that I want to extract is not wrapped in any tag properly.

```
<li class="tags">
   Required text: <span itemprop="testCat"><a href="/topics/new-topic/index.html" title="New Topic" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://www.example.com/topics/new-topic/index.html_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">New Topic</a></span>, <span itemprop="testCat"><a href="/topics/new-topic-2/index.html" title="New Topic" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://www.example.com/topics/new-topic-2/index.html_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">New Topic</a></span>, <span itemprop="testCat"><a href="/topics/new-topic-3/index.html" title="New Topic 3" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://www.example.com/topics/new-topic-3/index.html_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">New Topic 3</a></span>, 
   <div class="more">
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="more-trigger" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;javascript: void(0);_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">more</a>
      <div class="more-tags" style="top: 15px; left: 0px; display: none;">
         <div class="hd"></div>
         <div class="bd">
            <ul id="topic-filedin">
               <li>Another Required Text :
                  <a href="/topics/new-topic-4/index.html" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://www.example.com/topics/new-topic-4/index.html_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">New Topic 4</a>
               </li>
               <li>Topic Intended For :
                  <a href="/topics/for-kids/index.html" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://www.example.com/topics/for-kids/index.html_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">For Kids</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="ft"></div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         SNI.Node.ArticleInfo.moreTags();
      </script> 
   </div>
</li>
```

I am able to get the text wrapped inside the  tag using

```
$categories = $single_content->find('li[class=tags] span');
foreach ($categories as $key) {
  echo $key->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```

I am unable to find out `Required text` and `Another Required Text` and `Topic Intended For`.

Answer (score 0):

To get  'Another Required text' and 'Topic Intended For' You can use this -

$text = $single_content->find("ui[class=topic-filedin]/li");

$textArray = array();

foreach($text as $ta)

{

```
$textArray[] = $ta->plaintext;
```

}

You will get the required texts in an array.